# Finding a particular string from a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a file that contains one particular string many times. How can I print all occurrences of the string on the screen along with letters following that word till the next space is encountered.

Suppose a line contained:

```
example="123asdfadf" foo=bar
```

I want to print `example="123asdfadf"`.

I had tried using `less filename | grep -i "example=*"` but it was printing the complete lines in which example appeared.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] together with what you tried so far

Comment: `grep -o "example\b[^\s]*" yourfile` ?

Comment: less filename | grep -i "example=*"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre -- not working, it's returning nothing. Though,  Can you please explain this, I can try with it.

Edit : Sorry it worked too. I had to use "-i" to include all cases, my bad.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for pointing out. Edited the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -o "example[^ ]*" foo
example="abc"
example="123asdfadf"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Used -i along with -o to include all cases. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mb47, please check the green arrow to mark this answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since `-o` is only supported by GNU grep, a portable solution would be to use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(example=[^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p' file
```